# SR Suntour CR9 suspension cartridge removal

Tags: maintenance, suspension

How does one remove the cartridge of a [SR Suntour CR9](http://www.srsuntour-cycling.com/bike/forks/CR9-CR9-5001.html) cartridge? [This video](https://player.vimeo.com/video/140074797) shows how for other types, but the CR9 doesn't have the bottom bolt (you have to go in deep on the left side and unscrew a 5 mm allen bolt).

On a side note; when they "break the cap screw loose from cartridge shaft", they seem to be turning *clockwise*, which would make it tighter? I don't get that...

The CR9 seems a bit different. I undid the top cap, took out the splined gear (to which the knob attaches), and unscrewed the hollow 5mm allen bolt. What is left is a cartridge with a top cap:

[image: Unscrewed topcap]

If I undo the aforementioned bolt at the bottom of the left tube, I should be able to pull the lower legs down (can't do that yet; missing the long allen key)? But how can I pull them down with this top cap in the way?

Is that supposed to come off? I tried to get it off, but didn't want to yank too hard.

The ultimate goal is to re-grease the bushings and re-oil the wipers of the lower legs; nothing elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question; I used a bearing puller carefully, and it came loose. The cap was only pushed over the rod for about 1 mm, so applying some force by hand may have been enough.